# PHP.. not working on the Mac when I click on the file

Tags: php, html, eclipse, textwrangler

ex1.php

**code inside

```
<?php
   echo "hello world";
?>
```

I also tried this (ex2.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A PHP script</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>
<?php
    echo "hello world";
?>
</b>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: here is a [helpful link](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/02/screencast-mamp-installation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to run it from a webserver

```
http://localhost/ex1.php  #or whatever the path is.
```

or on the command line if php is installed in CLI you

```
php ex1.php
```

Visit [this site](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/02/screencast-mamp-installation.html) to see how to install MAMP on your mac and how it works.

Comment: how did yyou run it from the server? what is the url?

Comment: is it in the root folder? view the source of the file in the browser, make sure your server supports php, and that the extension is .php not .html

Comment: php is run on the server not on your machine, if you want to test it on your machine, follow the link i provided my answer

Comment: @jdl let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2339/discussion-between-ibu-and-jdl)